# PHP/MySQL Weekly Rota

Tags: php, mysql, queue

I have a list of users in a specific order. Each week I'd like to bump the order of the queue by one, for example

```
Week 1
User | Order
a    | 1
b    | 2
c    | 3

Week 2
User | Order
b    | 1
c    | 2
a    | 3
```

and so on...

Is there a simple way to achieve this with just PHP and MySQL?

Comment: is this a plain text example of you have it in a database already?

Comment: UPDATE table SET Order=Order-1; UPDATE table SET Order=MAX(Order)+1 WHERE Order=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a weekly cron job:

1. First you have to subtract 1 Order to all rows: `UPDATE TABLE SET Order = Order-1`
2. Then you have to change "0" value Order: `UPDATE TABLE SET Order = MAX(Order)+1 WHERE Order = 0`

If you have a restriction to "0" value in Order colummn:

1. First you have to change "1" value Order: `UPDATE TABLE SET Order = MAX(Order)+1 WHERE Order = 1`
2. Then you have to subtract 1 Order to all rows: `UPDATE TABLE SET Order = Order-1`

Comment: That's perfect. Is it possible without a cron job? Like storing the current week number in the database or something?

Comment: Yes... if you have a finite number of weeks. You can add a "Week" column, and for every week you can store a different pair of user and order. For example, user=a, order=1, week=1 . user=b, order=2, week=1 . user=a, order=2, week=2 . user=b, order=1, week=2. But if you don't know the number of weeks it will be a pain, when to stop?

Comment: I mean, get and store the intial week number (of the year) with date() or something then every time the weeks changes update it?

Comment: If you want to update something every X time (for example, every week), you have to use a cron job, or doing it manually...